# Xcode_OSX/Swift_NSPopUpButton.

Tags: macos, swift, nspopupbutton

I am incredibly new to this, so please keep that in mind!

I've been at this all night,  watched countless videos/haunted
countless forums...**I can't find one single answer!**

I am trying to make a basic popup menu in Swift/OSX  What I need to figure out is:

- How can I add more than the 'three items' to this menu
- Whatever is selected in the popup, for that info to send an integer
  value to another number.

I very much would appreciate your help,  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

A `NSPopupButton` is a container for a bunch of `NSMenuItem` objects so to add an item you can use

`func addItemWithTitle(_ title: String!)`

The `NSMenuItem` gets constructed for you by the call.

and as you may wish to start from scratch you can use

`func removeAllItems()`

To clean existing items from the button.

There are [also other methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPopUpButton_Class/index.html) around moving and removing menu items from the button.

A `NSPopupButton` is-a `NSControl` so you can use `var action: Selector` to set the action sent when an item is selected and `var target: AnyObject!` to control which object receives the message. Or just wire it up in `Interface Builder`.

```
protocol FooViewDelegate{
    func itemWithIndexWasSelected(value:Int)
}

class FooViewController: NSViewController  {

    @IBOutlet weak var myPopupButton: NSPopUpButton!
    var delegate: FooViewDelegate?

    let allTheThings = ["Mother", "Custard", "Axe", "Cactus"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        buildMyButton()
    }

    func buildMyButton() {
        myPopupButton.removeAllItems()

        myPopupButton.addItemsWithTitles(allTheThings)
        myPopupButton.target = self
        myPopupButton.action = "myPopUpButtonWasSelected:"

    }

    @IBAction func myPopUpButtonWasSelected(sender:AnyObject) {

        if let menuItem = sender as? NSMenuItem, mindex = find(allTheThings, menuItem.title) {
            self.delegate?.itemWithIndexWasSelected(mindex)
        }
    }


}
```

All the button construction can be done in `Interface Builder` rather than code too. Remember that you can duplicate items with `CMD-D` or you can drag new `NSMenuItem` objects into the button.