# NSPopupButton has nil value

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I am building an OS X desktop app that allows a user to select an item from a dropdown. I am trying to create an NSPopupButton menu like the response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421997/xcode-osx-swift-nspopupbutton/30428445#30428445), which is also very similar to [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/82046/introduction-to-os-x-tutorial-core-controls-and-swift-part-1), but when I build and run in Xcode, I get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error and the NSPopupButton evaluates to *nil* in the debugger. Did I miss a step initializing the menu? I also have a text input, but it works just fine. My code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var textInput: NSTextField!

  @IBOutlet weak var myMenu: NSPopUpButton!

  // other stuff here for processing textInput

  @IBAction func selectFromMyMenu(sender: NSPopUpButton) {
     let selection = myMenu.titleOfSelectedItem

      if selection == "Second Option" {
          // do something
      } else {
          // do something else - first option is default
      }
  }

  func setupMyMenu() {
     let menuItems = ["First Option", "Second Option"]
     myMenu.removeAllItems()
     myMenu.addItemsWithTitles(menuItems)
     myMenu.selectItemAtIndex(0)
 }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupMyMenu()
  }

  override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Usual question: Is the outlet connected in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes it is. I hooked it up graphically with the connector line, and it resulted in that `@IBOutlet weak var myMenu` line.

Comment: Obviously it was not ;-)

Comment: Xcode is a mischievous beast on occasion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reconnecting your button from the storyboard to your ViewController code.

Comment: This worked. On closer inspection, there was an empty circle next to the var.